# Left ideals of central simple algebra generated by symmetric element

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $\neq 2$. Suppose $(A,\sigma)$ is central simple algebra over a field $F$ with an orthogonal involution. Assume $(A,\sigma)$ is non-split. How to show that every left ideal is generated by a symmetric element?  It appears as an exercise in 'The Book of involution', Ch.I. Can somebody provide hint for doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to find a relevant definition of "orthogonal involution" on the internet... what is it? This book looks interesting, btw...

Comment: @rschwieb, when we consider $(A,\sigma)$ over its splitting field, $\sigma$ corresponds to bilinear form, if this bilinear form is symmetric, then involution is orthogonal.

Comment: Doh, now I have several more questions :P Are all these definitions in the book itself?

Comment: @rschwieb, yes. All these definitions are in the book.